# ConTeXt : side floats and background

Tags: floats, context

I just ran into a problem : I defined a randomized background for theorems (I just copied-pasted code found on the net for the MP part, since I am not a user of metapost ; an example of such a definition by Aditya can be found [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/mahajan/env-assign.pdf)). However, when I use it with a side float, the frame doesn't take it into account at all :

```
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=5cm]
\startuseMPgraphic{background:random}
  path p;
  for i = 1 upto nofmultipars :
    p = (multipars[i] topenlarged 0pt bottomenlarged 0pt) randomized 3pt ;
    fill p withcolor 0.95white ;
    draw p withcolor black withpen pencircle scaled \MPvar{linewidth};
  endfor;
  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic
\definetextbackground[axiomframe]
                     [mp=background:random,
                       location=paragraph,
                       rulethickness=1pt,
                       width=local,
                       leftoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,rightoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,
                       topoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,bottomoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,
                       before={\testpage[3]\blank},
                       after={\blank[2*medium]},
                     ]
\definedescription[theorem]
                  [text=,
                    before={\setupnarrower[middle=1cm]\startnarrower\startaxiomframe},
                    after={\stopaxiomframe\stopnarrower},
                    title=yes,
                    titlestyle=bold,
                    alternative=top,
                    inbetween=\nowhitespace]

\starttext

\starttheorem{Test}
  In this theorem, we test the background behavior. It seems to be alright for text, not
  for background.
\stoptheorem
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
In order to test the behavior in cas of side floats, we need a picture.
Let me introduce you the glorious CTAN lion :
\starttheorem{CTAN Lion}
  The CTAN Lion is very useful for tests. In this case, we can see that the background is
  not consistent with the figure, while the text is consistent.
\stoptheorem

The complex case is the one of very long text :
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
\starttheorem{Long blabla}
  \input knuth
\stoptheorem

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Ideally, I would like :
- if the side float was inserted before the theorem, the frame is reduced to the correct size and the text is this size all along
- if the theorem is too long, I choose to flush the side float before / insert the float inside the theorem frame (which works perfectly)

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is quite a hard problem.  What the sidefloats in ConTeXt do is use `\parshape` to shorten the correct amount of lines.  The problem is that while the paragraph is being built the correct linewidth is not available ([see this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308136/line-width-in-parshape-environment)).  Thus you cannot shrink the theorem box to the narrowed paragraph.  You can however flush the sidefloat before typsetting the theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think it is easily possible to make the sidefloats respect the narrowed paragraph of your theorems.  I also don’t think that it is easily feasible to have the theorem decide whether to flush the sidefloat or take it into account (which would be the same as problem 1).

You can however flush all sidefloats before the theorem environment by using `\flushsidefloats`.

```
\useexternalfigure
  [ctanlion]
  [http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png]
  [width=5cm]

\startuseMPgraphic{background:random}
  path p;
  for i = 1 upto nofmultipars :
    p = (multipars[i] topenlarged 0pt bottomenlarged 0pt) randomized 3pt ;
    fill p withcolor 0.95white ;
    draw p withcolor black withpen pencircle scaled \MPvar{linewidth};
  endfor;
  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definetextbackground
  [axiomframe]
  [
    mp=background:random,
    location=paragraph,
    rulethickness=1pt,
    width=local,
    leftoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,rightoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,
    topoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,bottomoffset=.5\bodyfontsize,
    before={\testpage[3]\blank},
    after={\blank[2*medium]},
  ]

\definedescription
  [theorem]
  [
    text=,
    before={\flushsidefloats
      \setupnarrower[middle=1cm]\startnarrower\startaxiomframe},
    after={\stopaxiomframe\stopnarrower},
    title=yes,
    titlestyle=bold,
    alternative=top,
    inbetween=\nowhitespace,
  ]

\starttext

\starttheorem{Test}
  In this theorem, we test the background behavior. It seems to be
  alright for text, not for background.
\stoptheorem
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
In order to test the behavior in cas of side floats, we need a
picture.  Let me introduce you the glorious CTAN lion :

\starttheorem{CTAN Lion}
  The CTAN Lion is very useful for tests. In this case, we can see
  that the background is not consistent with the figure, while the
  text is consistent.
\stoptheorem

The complex case is the one of very long text :
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
\starttheorem{Long blabla}
  \input knuth
\stoptheorem

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Don’t use `\page_otr_command_flush_side_floats`, what you can do is to add the `tall` keyword to `\placefigure` or use `\flushsidefloats` at the begin of the description, e.g. `\setupdescription[…][before=\flushsidefloats]`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'll work out every case independently then, and I'll decide if I want an automatic flush. Question for Metafox : what is the difference between `\page_otr_command_flush_side_floats` (that I didn't know) and `\flushsidefloats` (which I already knew and used) ?

Comment: `\flushsidefloats` is the user level form of the `\page_otr_command_flush_side_floats` command, the problem with internal commands is that key can be renamed or removed.